# Importing data as an array for plotting in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, import, text-files

I am new to this question. I hop to get benefit of your advice. Sorry if it is amateurish.

I have the following code which finally shows a plot. I just write one part of code.

```
...
cov = np.dot(A, A.T)
samps2 = np.random.multivariate_normal([0]*ndim, cov, size=nsamp)
print(samps2)
names = ["x%s"%i for i in range(ndim)]
labels =  ["x_%s"%i for i in range(ndim)]
samples2 = MCSamples(samples=samps2,names = names, labels = labels, label='Second set')
g = plots.getSubplotPlotter()
g.triangle_plot([samples2], filled=True)
```

It has no problem. The plot is drawn using the data coming from `samps2`. To see what the `samps2` is, we do `print(samps2)` and see:

```
[[-0.11213986 -0.0582685 ]
 [ 0.20346731  0.25309022]
 [ 0.22737737  0.2250694 ]
 [-0.09544588 -0.12754274]
 [-1.05491483 -1.15432073]
 [-0.31340717 -0.36144749]
 [-0.99158936 -1.12785124]
 [-0.5218308  -0.59193326]
 [ 0.76552123  0.82138362]
 [ 0.65083618  0.70784292]]
```

My question is, If I want to read these data from a `txt` file. what should I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways. What comes to my mind is:

plain python:

```
data = []
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append([float(num) for num in line.split()])
```

numpy:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt(filename, ...)
```

pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table(filename, sep='\s+', header=None)
```

Comment: Thank you so much my friend for you complete answer. I dont know why, but just `numpy` is working.

Comment: You're welcome. I think the three are very similar, except that pandas uses dataframes instead of plain arrays, but still: I don't know what you mean by _not_ working, so perhaps your approach for some reason fits only to numpy arrays, but not to lists or dataframes.